# Difference between LocalSettings and IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage, application-data

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App. I am able to use both the following registries:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

1. What are the differeces between these two?
2. Which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` and `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`is that the first one is the newer unified Windows Store App API whereas the latter is from the "old" Silverlight API.

New is not always better but I personally think you should go with the [modern version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) here. Both work with Silverlight but if you ever have to migrate your code to WinRT you will save yourself some time since the `IsolatedStorageSettings` API does not work under WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

There is huge difference in using both settings:

- [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx) works like a *Dictionary* and it's serialized and saved to *IsolatedStorageFile*:

  > IsolatedStorageSettings provide a convenient way to store user specific data as key-value pairs in a local IsolatedStorageFile.

  Also note that *IsolatedStorageSettings* **has to be** saved - [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save(v=vs.105).aspx). After saving you will find a file *__ApplicationSettings* in your app's isolated storage.
- [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) is an [ApplicationDataContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer.aspx). Once you add there a value, it's automatically saved. It's model [is conceptually equivalent to the Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517242/2681948).

So they are totally different thing, and if you add key to one of above *Settings* then it won't appear automatically in second. Consider two buttons:

```cs
const string firstKey = "firstKey";
const string secondKey = "secondKey";
IsolatedStorageSettings isoSetting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
ApplicationDataContainer localSetting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isoSetting.Add(firstKey, true);
    localSetting.Values[secondKey] = false;
    //isoSetting.Save(); // IsolatedStorageSettings have to be saved

    Debug.WriteLine("Is first key in LocalSettings: {0}", localSetting.Values.ContainsKey(firstKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is first key in ApplicationSettings: {0}", isoSetting.Contains(firstKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is second key in LocalSettings: {0}", localSetting.Values.ContainsKey(secondKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is second key in ApplicationSettings: {0}", isoSetting.Contains(secondKey));
}

private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // run this button after app restart without clicking first button
    // and saving IsoSettings
    Debug.WriteLine("Is first key in LocalSettings: {0}", localSetting.Values.ContainsKey(firstKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is first key in ApplicationSettings: {0}", isoSetting.Contains(firstKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is second key in LocalSettings: {0}", localSetting.Values.ContainsKey(secondKey));
    Debug.WriteLine("Is second key in ApplicationSettings: {0}", isoSetting.Contains(secondKey));
}
```

If I were writing a new app, then I would use new *ApplicationData.LocalSettings* API - it's newer and it will be much easier to port such an app to RunTime in the future, as WP8.1 RT doesn't support *IsolatedStorageSettings*.